# disable the buttons in the datatables which have no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datatables

I want to disable the pagination buttons when no data is there. i.e. when user is seeing the data in the last page the table will have last button disabled same with the first page and previous and next accordingly.

I have following code

```
$('#data_table').dataTable( {
                "aaData": dataSet,
                "aaSorting": [[0,'asc'],[0,'desc'],[2,'asc'],[2,'desc'],[3,'asc'],[3,'desc'],[4,'asc'],[4,'desc'],[5,'asc'],[5,'desc'],[6,'asc'],[6,'desc'],[7,'asc'],[7,'desc']],
                "iDisplayLength": 4,                
                "bInfo": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bAutoWidth": true
})
```

i have done the pagination part its working but when i m seeing the last page data i can still click on the last button and if i m seeing the first page data i can still click onthe first button. the button shud be disabled if we are on first page or on last page.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
.paginate_button_disabled {display: none; }
```

to your `CSS`.  This will only work for the "full_numbers" version of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Is that .dataTable() function adding a CSS class to the first and last buttons? Use Firebug to find out.

If so, just use CSS.

```
a.last-disabled { display: none; }
```

or jQuery and CSS:

```
$('a.last-disabled').css('color', '#ccc'); // grey out
$('a.last-disabled').click(function() { return false; });
```

Comment: my pagination nos and last , previous , first , next button are directly coming from the line "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" so how can i use css for that

Answer (score 0):

Well you could hide them through CSS i think.

```
.dataTables_paginate .ui-state-disabled {
     display:none;
}
```

if you provide an example on jsfiddle.net whe can help you better